# Set index of Regex matcher

Tags: .net, regex

I'm iterating over Regex matches in a .NET application using a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    if(SomeNonRegExCondition(m))
        continue; // no match

    ProcessMatch(m);
}
```

Unfortunately, the pattern matches too much if `SomeNonRegExCondition(m)` is `true` and I want to continue applying the `pattern` at `m.Index + 1` instead of `m.Index + m.Value.Length`. Is there an option with .NET to do this?

---

I'm not really sure what an additoinal MVCE brings to the table, however, it has been requested:

```
// consider this a sample pattern and a sample condition
// changing the pattern to not match in the first place is no option for me
const string input = "(abc)abcxyz";
const string pattern = "ab.*yz";

foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
  if ( /* some random condition, for MVCE using: */ match.Index == 1)
  {
    // Question: How to reset regex matcher in a way that it matches "abcxyz" at index 5
    continue;
  }

  Console.WriteLine (match);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Uhm, okay, if you think the question is more clear with a MVCE...here you go :-)

Comment: (please don't give me a no-solution telling me to change the regex to not producing a match in the first place...)

Comment: After I tried your code, I think you are following a wrong approach. If you need to check all substrings why not iterate over all of them and apply the anchored regex to them? It is not possible to manipulate the regex index in C#. Or, just fix your regex as `ab[^()]*yz`.

Comment: There is no kind of "substring" other than what the regular expression matches. Unfortunately, the conditions cannot be mapped to regular expressions. So if there is no chance for me to change the index I have to restart the matching at the given index. Thanks anyways...

Comment: It sounds as if you do not need the regex in the first place, and the problem is an XY problem.

Comment: Oh noes. MVCE than XY problem. The internet, I don't like it. Thank you anyways.

Comment: It is you who do not show all the cards. The solution below is something I have just conjured myself. `var rx = new Regex(pattern);
            string copy = input;
            var m = rx.Match(copy);
            while (m.Success || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(copy))
            {        if (m.Index > 1)
                {
                    copy = copy.Substring(1, copy.Length - 1);
                    m = rx.Match(copy);
                    continue;
                }
  copy = copy.Substring(1, copy.Length - 1);
  m = rx.Match(copy);
   Console.WriteLine(m.Value);   }`. Make little sense though.

Answer (score 1):

Switching the approach slightly, rather than finding all matches to start with using `.Matches`, instead use `.Match` to find the first one, and use `.NextMatch` to iterate through them.

This way, in your condition, you can completely change the match object by starting the matching process again with another call to `.Match` using a substring of where you've got to:

```
const string input = "(abc)abcxyz";
const string pattern = "ab.*yz";

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

while(match.Success) {
    if ( /* some random condition, for MVCE using: */ match.Index == 1)
    {
        //Start the matching process again at the next character, using Substring
        match = Regex.Match(input.Substring(match.Index+1), pattern);
        continue;
    }

    Console.Write(match); //abcxyz

    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is really no way to give the start index to `Regex.Match` - how performant is `input.Substring()`? Is it creating a view based on an existing string or is it creating a new string all the time?

Comment: => performance is bad. Hmm, need to use some kind of StringReader or something like that. Awful. Sometimes they don't provide an API for simplest things...in other areas the .NET RegEx API is really really good.

Comment: @D.R. I'm not sure providing an API point to switch the index would be any use performance wise, the regex engine will already have moved on beyond this match and be ready for the next one, to ignore the current match and begin matching again at the next character would probably involve a recompilation of whatever it does internally to do this work, much the same as doing a fresh call to `.Match` does anyway.